# Facebook Attribution ID, What is it?

Tags: java, android, facebook

i have found a method from Facebook SDK for android called:

```
ATTRIBUTION_ID_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider")
```

and it gives a string, that does not change (i think it would if you connect to another facebook account), i need some information about this attribution id, i tried to search google but i didnt find any.. (even in  facebook official developer website)
i need to know what it does, what you do with it and so.

Any information would help me. Thanks!

Comment: Come on, 15 views and no-one knows?

Comment: It is also transmitted with every request Header to facebook ads server: ATTRIBUTION_ID:  a186a5d3-344a-4e58-86a2-05a3a146132a

Answer (score 1):

It's used when you publish install data to Facebook, as part of mobile app install ads (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/).